# How do I read a specific line of text from a TXT file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

So say I wanted to `MsgBox` line 5 of a txt file, how would I do that? I've Googled for ages, but I can't seem to find anything of use to me.

Comment: You have no choice but to read all the previous lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`System.IO.File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
Dim line5 = File.ReadLines(pathToFile).ElementAtOrDefault(4)
If line5 IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show(line5)
End If
```

You need to add `Imports System.Linq` for the LINQ extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamReader class and only have to look the line(s) you want

```
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
fileReader =My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")
Dim stringReader As String
Dim linenum as Integer=0
While not fileReader.EndOfStream()
    stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    linenum = linenum + 1
    If linenum = 5 Then
        MsgBox(stringReader)
        Exit While  'If you are done here
    End If
End While
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Same answer with just 7 more lines? At least jump out of the loop after the line has been found

Comment: It's not the same answer, I'm not using LINQ. But you're right, an exit out of the loop is needed. I'll edit.